# Rails Creating a json only api and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I'm adding an api to an existing application.

I created a controller "api" and am using rabl to handle my views and return json.

Ideally I want the routes to be something like this: (We have a User controller and model set up).

/api/users/show.json?id=1 etc...

I have the api/index.json working and returning my rabl template, but I can't seem to get the /api/users/show.json to do anything

I set this up:

```
scope "/api" do
  resources :users
end
```

But that redirects from "/api/users" to "/users/new"

I'd like to keep everything in the api section to itself, and not have to mix up my rabl templates within the views/users or in the users controller.

Thanks for any light you might be able to shed on this.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing Ooops not very constructive but If you prefer to keep your API stuff scoped in one directory, use `namespace`

Comment: Yeah, tried that- get a "Unitialized contstant "Api" error

Comment: `namespace :api do` raises this error? Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i got your problem, but i think your route may be wrong.

It should be something like

```
/api/users/1.json
```